# Firebase Database setValue: or removeValue failed: permission_denied iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ios10

I'm trying to write data to Firebase Database but I keep receiving the following error when my saved button is pressed.

> 2016-12-02 11:09:42.548 StartupNow[1482:60415] [FirebaseDatabase] setValue: or removeValue: at /test/-KY-VpLZWbp4vjF3BpMk failed: permission_denied

**Things I've tried:**
I've made sure my .read and .write rules were set to true in my console, reconnected my savedButtonPressed button, and wrote the Firebase reference in a function and called it in my savedButtonPressed() method.

**Extra Resource** Here is the tutorial I'm following along. https://youtu.be/F42CzqIBxHQ?t=4m14s

```
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

}

@IBAction func saveButtonPressed() {
   // TODO: Post data to Firebase

    firebaseChild()
    print("********************************")
    print("********************************")

}

func firebaseChild () {
    ref?.child("Test").childByAutoId().setValue("Hello Firebase")

}
```

Comment: have you make sure that the user is authenticated in firebase because that is the initial rules set in database to access.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FreddieOh and I chatted over Slack, and the problem was that the database that was listed in the `GoogleService-info.plist` file didn't match up with the one he was editing. (It looks like maybe in this case, he had deleted and recreated the project in the Firebase console, but hadn't updated the plist file.)

If you find yourself in the same situation where you've set your read and write access to true and are still getting permission denied errors, open up your `GoogleService-info.plist` file and look at the entry for  `DATABASE_URL`. Then go to the Firebase Database in your project, look at the top of the data tab, and confirm that the URL listed there is the same as the one in your plist file.

I suppose the other thing to check for would be that you updated your database rules to allow global access but forgot to click the Publish button. That... may have happened to me at one point. :)

Comment: Thank You After Changing Top tab to realtime database then i see this and make it true Working like charm :-)

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue. It was resolved by resetting the read / write rules for the database. If you changed your rules try reseting them to the default.

**Warning: These rules allow anyone to read and write to your database!**

**Default Rules for Real-time Database**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

**Default Rules for Cloud Firestore**

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that's risky. you don't wanna have them all on default

Comment: I agree. The idea here isn't to leave the default database rules. The idea is that by reseting them you can determine if the issues is with your updated rules. Then you canstart correcting that mistake is need be.

Comment: This code is not working on the latest version of Firebase console.

Comment: @kyo those are the default rules that Firebase provides. Are you looking at the real-time database or the newer cloud-store? These rules are for the real-time database.

Answer (score 10):

**Go to your Firebase console, and perform following steps which is identify in image.**

Please lookup image and follow these steps. If you are beginner and facing problem in image. I make little video about error.

**Video Solution :** 
https://youtu.be/FcQCPqckvqo

**Image Solution**
[image]

Comment: you save my life

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the same issue after trying to use every resource. The only solution is that

Go to fireBase Console -->select your project -->Go to database -->select the Rules("Show in the mid next to the  Data")-->make the make both option true

```
{  
    "rules": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
```

this will be work perfectly

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should always keep in mind that setting your read and write rules to true is not recommended for production. `It is essential that you configure these rules correctly before launching your app to ensure that your users can only access the data that they are supposed to. `

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart?authuser=1

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to select **real time database** and edit the rule then publish .[image]